# Haproxy Loadbalancer andt IIS Binding

Tags: iis, binding, haproxy

I have configured an haproxy http loadbalancer to listen on port 80.There are two windows servers which serve as web servers listening on port 81 .The websites on the backend can only be accessed with the urls:
http://matrix-1.zone.lk:81,
http://matrix-2.zone.lk:81

These websites show up when they are accessed through the browser directly.But when i access them through the loadbalancer i get an error.The haproxy config is given below:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log                     global
    retries                 3
    timeout queue           1000s
    timeout connect         86400000s
    timeout client          86400000s
    timeout server          86400000s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 30000

listen http-in 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    server MATRIX-1 matrix-1.zone.lk:81
    server MATRIX-2 matrix-2.zone.lk:81
```

Could someone tell me whats wrong??..thanks in advance3

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? It may help you get a better answer.

Comment: I get this Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.